# irreducibility in p-adic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $u\in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ be a unit in the ring of $p$-adic integers. Assume that $u^{1/p}\not\in \mathbb{Q}_p$, in other words $u$ is not a $p$-power.

I am wondering how the polynomial $f=x^p-u$ factors over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. I managed to prove (without using that $u$ is a unit) that f is irreducible if and only if it has no roots.

However, if $f$ has a root $\alpha$, then we have
$$
f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)
$$

I am wondering, do we know if $g$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or how it factors?

Comment: How can $f$ be irreducible if it has a root?

Comment: [to be taken in response to the comment below] ...in that case feel free to just take the description of the roots from my answer I guess :)

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I meant f is irreducible if and only if it has no roots. (in particular, f reducible => f must have a root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$). I edited my question, thanks for your point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim that $f$ is irreducible, independent of concrete choice of $u$.

Note that we know all the roots of $f$: They are of the form $\zeta_p^k u^{1 / p}$ for $\zeta_p$ a primitive $p$th root of unity, $u^{1 / p}$ an initial choice of root and $k = 1, \ldots, p$. Let now $K = \mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$. Clearly $L = K(u^{1 / p})$ is a splitting field for $f$, and $\operatorname{Gal}(L / K) \cong \mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ generated by $u^{1 / p} \mapsto \zeta_p u^{1 / p}$ (to make this completely rigorous you could apply to Kummer theory) which implies that $f$ is irreducible over $K$ and hence also over the smaller field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (since $f$ clearly has no roots in $K$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(L / K)$ acts transitively on its roots).

Note also that this does not use that $u$ is a $p$-adic unit, or in fact anything about the ground field *except* that it is not of characteristic $p$ (this assumption is hidden away in my appeal to Kummer theory), so the proof translates freely to other settings.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. In particular, this proof implies that if the root $u^{1/p} \not\in \mathbb{Q}_p$, then none of the roots belonged to $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: @did Yes, but there's a subtlety here: There is generally no canonical $u^{1 / p}$. You see, if we were talking about $\mathbb{Q}$, then you can talk about something like a _principal_ fifth root of 2, say, by which you mean the unique fifth root of 2 lying in $\mathbb{R}$. But you have no equivalent of $\mathbb{R}$ here, and Galois theory tells you that a priori the roots of $f$, i.e. all the candidates for $u^{1 / p}$, are not distinguishable. That's why I say "initial choice of root": You have to pick one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I agree there is no special root. But I think we can have the case $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$, where the initially picked root $u^{1/p}\not\in \mathbb{Q}_p$ and it is a root of $g(x)$ and there is another root $\alpha=\zeta_p^i u^{1/p} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ with $i\neq 0$. In this case my question will be phrased: is g irreducible?

Comment: @did so you're asking what happens if $\mathbb{Q}_p$ contains _one_ root of $f$? In that case yes, $g$ will be irreducible, by essentially the same argument: The Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}_p(g) / \mathbb{Q}_p)$ acts transitively. The archetypal example here is the $p$th roots of unity: $x^p - 1$ always has a single root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, namely 1, and if you split that factor off you get a cyclotomic polynomial which is irreducible.

Comment: @did Note also that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ contains exactly 0, 1, or all roots of $f$: If it contains $u^{1 / p}$ and $\zeta_p^i u^{1 / p}$, then it contains $\zeta_p^i$, and since $p$ is prime this root of unity is primitive, so you get all the other $\zeta_p^j u^{1 / p}$ as well.

Comment: An example with one root: $x^3 - 2$ has one root in $\mathbf Q_5$ that is $3 \bmod 5$: it's $(x-\alpha)(x^2+\alpha x + \alpha^2)$ where $\alpha = 3 + 2\cdot 5^2 + 2\cdot 5^3 + 3\cdot 5^4 + 5^5 + \cdots$.  The quadratic factor has discriminant $-3\alpha^2 \equiv 3 \bmod 5$, so it is not a square in $\mathbf Q_5$.